# How to check for two elements in one set in a list

Tags: c#

```
username = UserInterface.GetInput("Enter your username");
password = UserInterface.GetPassword("Enter your password");
if (regusers.Contains(new Users { Username = $"{username}", Password = $"{password}", Phone = "" }) == true)
{          
    UserInterface.Message($"Welcome {username}");
}
else
{
    UserInterface.Message("Username and/or password is incorrect.");
}
```

I want to be able to check if the username and password match up with a set in the list but this will only check for a username and I'm unsure how to do so. I know where my approach to the problem lies.

```
public class Users : IEquatable<Users>
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Users other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.Username.Equals(other.Username));
    }
}
List<Users> regusers = new List<Users>();
```

But how would I do the same sort of check with the password as I did with the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only check Uername in this line

```
return (this.Username.Equals(other.Username));
```

Check name and pass.

```
public bool Equals(Users other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return (this.Username.Equals(other.Username) && this.Password.Equals(other.Password));
}
```

And never store pass in plaintext, use hashes for store paswords.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are all strings, you can simply compare all of them.

```cs
public bool Equals(Users other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return (userName == other.userName) && (password == other.password);
}
```